# is the golang aws sdk for s3 throttled?

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go

I'm using go aws sdk to put object to s3.  It takes about 1 second to upload the file.  To test the concurrency, I have an http server that I hit with `ab -c10 -n10 http://localhost:8080` and the handler calls this code:

```
func (service *Service) LogResponseManager(resp gorequest.Response, s3key string) {
    uploader := service.S3Manager
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    params := &s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket:      aws.String("cslogs.sellbrite.com"), // Required
        Key:         aws.String(s3key),                  // Required
        Body:        resp.Body,
        ContentType: aws.String("text/plain"),
    }
    uploader.Upload(params)

}
```

I'm using the echo server to receive requests and if I were to just sleep 1 second in the handler the time to execute all 10 requests in parallel is just 1 second.  However when uploading too s3, the time to execute 10 concurrent requests seems to be adding up in serial, close to 8 seconds.  Is the go sdk not executing s3 uploads concurrently?

Comment: After trying different numbers out with apache benchmark I've come to the conclusion that it is running concurrently.  For small increases of concurrency, the overall time to complete the requests decreases but the duration for each request increases.  I wonder if maybe I'm throttled based on my out going bandwidth?

Comment: Can you spin up a micro VM in AWS, local to S3, and run your test there? Eliminate your network from the equation.

Comment: The AWS SDK for Go uses the same API calls that every other SDK (and the AWS CLI tools) use; any limits on throughput should be identical.

Comment: try randomising the key that you're uploading to.  
eg bucket/aa/file1.jpg
bucket/ab/file2.jpg

I remember reading somewhere that you have to distribute the access using different key, otherwise all access will be pointing to a same endpoint.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html